# How do I force jQuery to load first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-select

I am trying to add bootstrap-select to my Flask app and I keep running into the error "TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function". Everything I've read says this only occurs if you load jQuery again after loading bootstrap-select.js, so I went through and cleaned up my scripts, ensuring that jQuery was being loaded before all my other JS scripts, like so:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"> </script>
...
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

However, I was still getting the same problem. I decided to take a look at the order of loading in the chrome developer tools window, and now I think my problem is this: jQuery is being *queued* for loading before bootstrap-select, but it's not actually *starting* the download until after bootstrap-select has already finished. I suspect this is because of the difference in size between the two.

Is there any way I can force my other scripts to delay loading until after jQuery has already loaded? Or if I figure out how to cache a copy of jQuery in my static directory, will that help?

**Edit:** Wow, okay, I got a lot of comments on this! To try and clarify as much as possible, I'm just going to make some notes:

- After thoroughly checking all my scripts, I can confirm that only one copy of jQuery is being loaded.
- This is not an https page, I'm running it locally on a Flask development server.
- I checked the bootstrap-select url I have in my code and it is the correct one. Sorry, I'm not sure why it left out the dash when I was copy-pasting. I have corrected the question accordingly.
- I have been using the Network tab in chrome's dev tools to check loading successes/times.
- I moved my jQuery to the very beginning of the file to ensure it would load first, and I can now confirm it is finished loading before bootstrap-select loads.

Despite all this, I'm continuing to get the same error, so if anyone has other suggestions I would appreciate them. I'm completely out of ideas at this point.

Comment: Ah, sorry. That was a typo when I was creating the question, I checked and it's not in the original code.

Comment: So long as you do not put `defer` on the script tag, the browser should load those scripts in the order that you put them in the document.

Comment: we do not know all that's going on in your code. it is very possible something else loads another copy of jQuery somewhere else and since things might be async, you get to see that problem appear later on.

Comment: The page that this is on, is it an `https` page?  If so, the page may be refusing to load jQuery because you are trying to load it over `http` and that's mixed content.

Comment: I don't think SelectPicker is in jQuery.  Are you loading the jQuery select picker plugin separately?

Comment: @nixkuroi selectpicker is a bootstrap-select method.  Which is the second script include they are doing ...

Comment: Ok, in that case, have you looked at the Network tab in dev tools to see the order that they're being loaded?

Comment: Actually, I just tried the URL: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrapselect/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js  - it came back with a 404.

Comment: Posted the correct url to the bootstrap select library in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution and it's dumb as heck.

I was adding my scripts to the same place the previous developer added theirs, in the base template that all my other templates extend. The thing is, they added theirs to the end of the page, after the body tag was closed (presumably to make page loading faster). The little bit of jQuery which was using selectpicker was *in* the body, and was thus trying to load the function prematurely.

Thanks for all your answers!

Answer (score 1):

You should put `defer` at the end of both script tags, so they are loaded in order no matter what, like this:

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
...
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrapselect/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the URL for your bootstrap select library to:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js